# Is Oauth2 authorization code bound with the client id?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I tried to login with two separate website, both using "login with Google". Intercepted the auth code from the 1st site, and exchange it with the auto code to the 2nd site. Neither site will let me login. I remember in RFC6749 it is not specified that the auth code to be bound with any identity, is it implemented so to increase security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed part of OAuth2.0 security:

> **Exchange the Authorization Code for an Access Token**
>
> We’re about ready to wrap up the flow. Now that the application has
> the authorization code, it can use that to get an access token.
>
> The application makes a POST request to the service’s token endpoint
> with the following parameters:
>
> grant_type=authorization_code - This tells the token endpoint that the
> application is using the Authorization Code grant type.
>
> code - The
> application includes the authorization code it was given in the
> redirect.
>
> redirect_uri - The same redirect URI that was used when
> requesting the code. Some APIs don’t require this parameter, so you’ll
> need to double check the documentation of the particular API you’re
> accessing.
>
> client_id - The application’s client ID.
>
> client_secret -
> **The application’s client secret. This ensures that the request to get
> the access token is made only from the application, and not from a
> potential attacker that may have intercepted the authorization code.**

from https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type#exchange-the-authorization-code-for-an-access-token

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the post is a bit misleading. Look at the next sentence, "The token endpoint will verify all the parameters in the request, ensuring the code hasn’t expired and that the client ID and secret match." My understanding is the client_secret is to used verify it is indeed sent from the client_id

Comment: It's more than that... it is also used to check that the authorisation code that the server issued is for the same client_id that you are now asking for the access code for.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer : Authorization code is bound to the client it was issued**

This is strictly enforced by the RFC6749 and stated in [4.1.3.  Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) section. Also, it is one of many checkes authorization server perform to validate a token request. Specification has following stated,

> The authorization server MUST:
>
> o **ensure that the authorization code was issued to the authenticated
> confidential client, or if the client is public, ensure that the code
> was issued to "client_id" in the request**

So when authorization server will cross check authorization code against client id or client credentials depending on client type.

Furthermore, authorization code is a temporary secret which must not be exposed to other parties. This is highlighted in security consideration's [10.5.  Authorization Codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5) section.